# jquery validate() not accepting datepicker format

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Using jQuery datepicker, with the dateFormat of `d M, yyyy`

But when there is validation on the form - this format is not accepted.

This is what I have on the form:

```
$(".validate").validate();
$('.datepicker').datepicker({autoclose: true, format: "d M, yyyy"});
```

and here is my [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/emko0hzr/)

Thanks!

Comment: Your problem has ***absolutely nothing to do with*** the jQuery Validate plugin.  I completely removed it and you have the same issue:  http://jsfiddle.net/emko0hzr/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original Title:

> "jquery validate() not accepting datepicker format"

Your date formatting issue has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery Validate.  Completely remove the jQuery Validate plugin and see the same issue: [jsfiddle.net/emko0hzr/2](http://jsfiddle.net/emko0hzr/2)

---

Your Datepicker code is flawed:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({autoclose: true, format: "d M, yyyy"});
```

There are no such options called `autoclose` or `format` listed anywhere in [the documentation for the jQuery UI Datepicker Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Rather, the `dateFormat` option is used for formatting the date output...

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: "d M, yy"});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/emko0hzr/3/**

NOTE:  There is also no such date format as `yyyy`.  It's `yy`, otherwise, this year would be displayed as `"20152015"`.

---

**EDIT:**

As per your comment, the Datepicker pops up on the date fields.  That is because these fields are flagged as "invalid" and brought into focus as per the jQuery Validate plugin.  You have a `maxlength="10"` attribute on the date fields and the jQuery Validate plugin will automatically use these inline HTML 5 validation attributes for its rules.  Since the date within the field does not meet this `maxlength` rule, it's flagged as invalid.  The plugin will bring any invalid field into focus; and bringing your date field into focus will automatically bring up the Datepicker window.  Simply remove the inline `maxlength` attribute and put more sensible validation rules into place.

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/emko0hzr/4/**

Comment: Thanks. I looked at your demo. The question is when i try submit - why does the datepicker automatically open up - as though the date there is not acceptable?

Comment: @kneidels, that's because the date fields are still **invalid** as per your inline `maxlength="10"` validation attribute.  The jQuery Validate plugin will _automatically_ use any HTML 5 validation attributes.  Remove that attribute/rule and it works fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/emko0hzr/4/

Comment: so it was because of the validation ;)
. just kidding. Thanks for the help!